# Options for invisibly mounting slats on ceiling & walls

Tags: design, panel, mounting

I'm building out a van conversion and want to mount a few dozen wooden slats to the walls and ceilings, similar to the picture below.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do this with invisible mounts.

My first thought was keyhole slots, but that's probably not a great option for a moving vehicle. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: If the image you use in your question isn't yours, make sure you [edit] the question and clearly give credit to the rightsholder of the image.

Comment: Do you need the mounting to be truly invisible or would just unobtrusive/very hard to see be sufficient? And do you know yet what species the slats will be? This might be directly relevant to what would be unobtrusive enough to be acceptable, since tiny brad holes would hide better on e.g. red oak compared to, say, maple, or any of the softwoods. *"My first thought was keyhole slots"* Oddly, they are the first thing I thought of too! But as you say possibly not ideal for a moving vehicle..... although the total friction in the 'system' might actually make this more secure than we are thinking.

Comment: @Graphus - I don't *need* it to be invisible, but we're planning on spending 5 years or so driving around the world in this van, so it's just a preference thing.  And it's all going to be Hinoki (Cypress), so a very light color.

Comment: Ah cypress, then my idea may not work then but I'll mention it anyway as it's one option to consider.

Comment: Since a couple of the recommendations hinge on it, what thickness are you planning the slats to be?

Comment: BTW any concerns about hinoki being a little soft for this application? Its low specific gravity points to a low hardness (in the ballpark of poplar, sitka spruce, maybe even white pine) which in a confined space may mean it'll end up being pretty beat up.

Comment: As thin as I can, depending on what mounting solution I decide to end up going with, since even an inch takes up a non-negligible portion of available space and I only have about 1,200kg to play with for the entire thing (including water, batteries, mattress, passengers, dog, ...).  I'm somewhat leaning towards pins after your answer. As for Hinoki -- Yeah, I thought of that, but floors and walls aren't very high traffic ;)  And have you ever smelled it?  It's amazing!  The back part of the van is going to be convertible to a sauna as well, and Hinoki is the absolutely ideal wood for that IMO.

Answer (score 4):

**Option #1, brads or nails**
A brad nailer or pin nailer may be a good solution here, with or without the help of a little adhesive.

The smallest gauges of brads and pins (18-23 gauge) shot from nailers produce very small holes that are considered unobtrusive enough that many don't even bother to fill them. And with 23 gauge the holes are so tiny that they are very hard to locate even when you know they're there on woods that have visible grain lines — this sadly is not the case with the cypress you plan to use, but I think this is still an option worth exploring<sup>1</sup>. A picture's worth a thousand words here so:

[image: Brad v. pin nailer holes compared]

<sup>**Source:** [Shop Gadget: 23-Gauge Pin Nailers](https://www.woodsmith.com/article/23-gauge-pin-nailers-pin-nailer-features-from-common-to-unique/) on Woodsmith.</sup>

In addition to being relatively cheap (*verrry* cheap if you can rent or borrow the nailer) this solution will also make installation really fast.

While the hold from a 23-gauge pin nails is usually considered too weak to hold anything permanently by themselves shooting them in dovetail fashion, like this \ / instead of like this | | will increase the holding power greatly. You'd need to do some experiments — particularly incorporating vibration I think — to confirm they'd work for your application, whether they'd be enough on their own. If you have doubts a tiny dab of adhesive could be added to each pinning location<sup>2</sup>; between the two of them I can't imagine the hold would not be sufficient, and lasting.

**Option #2, *don't* aim for invisible**
If you abandon the idea of invisible mounting entirely you could embrace a number of options where you make a *feature* of how the slats are attached.

Brass slot-head screws have long been considered attractive enough that they can be seen on fine furniture, and combined with brass cup washers (AKA countersunk washers) they make an even better-looking fastening solution:

[image: Brass cup washers image]

But not gonna lie, this would make installation *considerably* slower.

If you don't need a completely flush installation normal brass cup washers, which raise the screw head very slightly above the surface, are also quite attractive and offer significantly easier installation.

---

<sup>1</sup> The holes could be filled and made practically invisible *if* you plan to finish the wood, however this would involve a fair amount of extra effort for perhaps minimal gain.

<sup>2</sup> Rather than normal wood glues PU construction adhesive or another product that works similarly may be perfect for this since the noticeable film between the slats and the nailing strips or other backing will help dampen vibration.

Comment: Honestly, this is the right answer. Aim for safe, secure, and pretty enough.

Comment: And, yes, I'd choose an adhesive that allows for movement and does not get brittle because there is no van box on the planet that doesn't flex under normal driving loads. Rubber cement to reduce squeaks might be an idea, though I might just use small squares of indestructible butyl tape for that. The strength is in the fasteners. For noise reduction the most important thing to do is to treat the metal box with acoustic sealant before laying down the subframe that slats live on. Wood is great, but for automotive stuff butyl compounds are _always_ the right choice when starting from bare metal.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a few options:

- **Screws installed from the back.** If you can build the slat panels outside the van and then install them, you can screw through the supports into the back of the slats. This would give you the secure, invisible connection you're looking for.
- **Nails or staples from the sides.** If you're lining the walls of an entire van with slats, you'll want fasteners that go in fast and work well. I can't think of a better tool for that than a nail gun or a staple gun. If you fire the fasteners at an angle through the sides of the slats and into the supports, they should be pretty well hidden. A dab of glue at each joint could also help.
- **Glue or construction adhesive.** (Credit to aebabis for suggesting this first.) Adhesives can be very strong, and again you'll get that invisible connection. Installation will be much slower than with a nail gun since you'll need to clamp each joint until the glue cures.
- **Magnets.** Probably not ideal for the whole project, but if there are areas where you might need to remove a slat for access, magnets might be a solution. If you inset steel magnet cups with rare earth magnets on one side of the joint and inset steel washers on the other side, you can get a connection that won't come apart until you want it to.
- **Keyholes.** You suggested it, and I think they could be a good idea. To make it work, you'll need the following: 1) A way to locate all the keyholes and the mating screws precisely, so that they'll all line up; 2) a gauge to set the height of all the screws the same way; 3) some sort of thin, compressible material (weatherstripping?) to go between slats and supports and stop rattling, because you'll never get all those connections tight; 4) a way to lock the slats in place once installed. On that last point, I imagine sliding the slats into place, and then installing a piece across the ends that stops them from sliding backward.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Magnets genius! Wood looks too thin for screws from back.

Comment: @VolframK I think the photo is some other van, just to help us understand the goal. If the slats are thick enough that the OP considered keyholes and screws, it’s thick enough to screw into.

Comment: The thickness required for a good amount of threads biting but not emerging from the top is probably more than that required for a keyhole. Given that we see that we want to hang stuff from the slats (as that is the design obvious from the photo) I'd be inclined to distrust keyholes as well.

Comment: @jdv Hard to say for sure... if you zoom in on the areas where you can see the supports, the thickness of the slats appears to be maybe 1/3 the width of the slats. But again, the photo is obviously not the OP's vehicle, so we really don't know how thick the OP is planning to make the slats. And it's the OP that first considered keyholes; I only meant to point out that there are solutions to problems like rattling and unwanted detachment. I think the best option is a combination of glue or construction adhesive, and finish nails angled through the sides of the slats.

Comment: I would recommend not using glue, actually. The glue joint will break anyway because of the box torsion -- unless you stiffen up the box with a roll cage. I'd use thin rubber (or wax) where we can expect squeaks, similar to how cars support their sprung weight with rubber where struts and torsion members meet.

Comment: Magnets are one of those cool things that I would not want to rely on. Once it lets go, it just lets go. The only failure method is a sudden one -- not something you want in an application that can be subject to 1G of force. I'd design for 2Gs just to build in some safety.

Comment: @jdv The thing about magnets that you can make them as strong as you want. Steel cups significantly increase force needed to pull them apart. If steel washers on one side isn’t strong enough, put magnets on both sides. Or stack them up. I wouldn’t use them for all the slats (too expensive), and I’d be thoughtful about safety in a collision, but they’re definitely a viable option where slats need to be removable.

Comment: @Caleb I might reserve that for "ports" or places intended for removal to get at some feature. It isn't going to be the right thing for long-term permanent installation for an entire wall. They are expensive and will be hard to field repair. Magnetism is also one of the forces that is super strong close up, but the hold drops significantly drops with distance. and, like I said, regardless of the strength, the failure mode is sudden. Not what you want for an entire feature in a moving vehicle.

Comment: @jdv That’s exactly what I suggested. Magnetism obeys the inverse square law, so it does drop off, but no other option mentioned here provides *any* attraction at any distance, so I’m not sure why that’s a complaint. If you don’t want to use magnets in your van, that’s fine, but they’re a fine option in the right situation.

Comment: Hold of point of screw is weak, same as short screw. And also this is very soft wood! But still +1 :)

Comment: @jdvm, yes keyhole slots also not possible here I think. Wood is too thin and too soft

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any DIY truly hidden fastener solutions for this application but there are many proprietary systems for doing so. Just search for "invisible mounting wood slats".

For decks and other larger dimensioned projects you can use a jig to come in at an angle on the inside edge, but I don't see that working out well for this application. You might be able to adapt one of the decking systems out there, but few of those are truly "hidden" as they often require special fasteners that are tucked in between the decking, or even special decking. This is clearly not what you are looking for with this kind of cleat style project.

So, I think you are going to have to go with one of the fancy proprietary hidden fastener systems sold for these sorts of commercial applications.

Though, the photo in your question is using staples or brads of some kind, which is a pretty clean install.

I should mention that I have owned a converted van in my life, and relying on friction (such as a keyhole) or glue is a Bad Idea. Vans flex. A lot. The stuff in vans gets thrown around, even on ordinary roads you can expect to want to take vans. A lot. Those joints will have to allow for this. And you cannot expect gravity to always work in your favour. A keyhole, when done right, is sort of a good friction fit. But it can easily be overcome.

And you should consider how to make it field repairable. Some fancy expensive method that requires special fasteners or tools is a bad idea. You *will* be repairing this on the road, eventually. Being able to do that with only a handful of screws and a driver of some sort is worth much more than the interior being Instagram ready.

Since the application here is clearly a storage solution, you have to treat it like one. If you make something that looks like French cleats, then you have to build it like French cleats. Assume that this van will be subject to forces twice what you feel on an emergency stop. Will it release several kilos of wood and tackle to the back of your head if that happens?

You 100% need a positive mechanical fastener than can handle *at least* a few Gs fully loaded. This is a place where form must follow function. Your constraint must be safety and durability, not cosmetics. And then see what you can design.

A rule of thumb is to treat this build like you are building a boat. Things need to be lashed down, and the things you are lashing to have to be connected to something else with a lot of fasteners.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it to come apart, wood glue should be enough.

Comment: But how to hold slats in place while glue sets?

Comment: In an environment subject to large variations in temperature and humidity, and lots of knocks, vibration, and torsion where you are also expecting to hang mass from the slats (these are basically allowing for "French" cleats) even if you _could_ get the perfect glue joint (and that is debatable) I'm not sure I'd want to trust _any_ glue only joint in this application. In fact, this is the sort of joinery where you want to use no glue at all, because vans flex. A lot.